# How to show a spinner loader between the one route to another route in angular 4, I am geeting events but not able to show the loader

Tags: angular, routes, loader

I currently working on a project where they require a loader between two routes. I am getting the route events too but I am not able to see the loader

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
Router,
// import as RouterEvent to avoid confusion with the DOM Event
Event,
NavigationStart,
NavigationEnd,
NavigationCancel,
NavigationError
} from '@angular/router'

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
title = 'boroughmuir-init-map';

loading = true;

constructor(private router: Router) {
 router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
   this.navigationInterceptor(event)
 })
}

 // Shows and hides the loading spinner during RouterEvent changes
 navigationInterceptor(event: Event): void {
  if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
     this.loading = true;
  }
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
  this.loading = false;
  }

  // Set loading state to false in both of the below events to hide the 
  spinner in case a request fails
   if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
    this.loading = false;
  }
  if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
    this.loading = false;
  }
}



}
```

app.component.html

```
  <div class="loader" *ngIf="loading"></div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Kindly help m,e to solve this issue. I not getting the loader, but I am getting the events in the console.

app.component.css

```
.loader {
border: 16px solid #BE9F58;
border-radius: 50%;
border-top: 16px solid #212529;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
-webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:calc(50% - 48px);
transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
z-index: 1000;
  }

 /* Safari */
 @-webkit-keyframes spin {
   0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
 }

 @keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
 }
```

the Css for the loader

Comment: could you please add your loader CSS, I think you didn't add CSS for loader class

Comment: Hi @arunkumar I have edited the post and added the css for the loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove NavigationCancel and NavigationError, If you are not using route guards in your app, You will get NavigationCancel event only if you have route guards and that return false during navigation. You can check that by passing {enableTracing : true} object in routerModule

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
      this.navigationInterceptor(event);
    });
  }

  navigationInterceptor(event: Event): void {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      this.loader = true;
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      // Hide loading indicator
      this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        this.loader = false;
      }, 1000);
    }
    // if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
    //   this.loader = false;
    // }
    // if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
    //    console.log(event);
    //   this.loader = false;
    // }

  }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-spinner-example-bcedjq

Comment: Hey @Chellappan It worked for me but the loader goes off when the route is displayed it should go off when the data from the API is loaded and the dom elements are loaded on the respective route.

Comment: If you want to show spinner for http response i would suggest to use http interceptor. For More Info Check this:https://blog.angularindepth.com/top-10-ways-to-use-interceptors-in-angular-db450f8a62d6

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor change in your import section:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
Router,
// import as RouterEvent to avoid confusion with the DOM Event
Event as RouterEvent,
NavigationStart,
NavigationEnd,
NavigationCancel,
NavigationError
} from '@angular/router'

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
title = 'boroughmuir-init-map';

loading = true;

constructor(private router: Router) {
 router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
   this.navigationInterceptor(event)
 })
}

 // Shows and hides the loading spinner during RouterEvent changes
 navigationInterceptor(event: RouterEvent): void {
  if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
     this.loading = true;
  }
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
  this.loading = false;
  }

  // Set loading state to false in both of the below events to hide the 
  spinner in case a request fails
   if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
    this.loading = false;
  }
  if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
    this.loading = false;
  }
}
```

}

The event that you are trying to compare needs to be of type RouterEvent and not just normal Event. I hope it helps!